# What's the correct format for Java APNS certificate?

Tags: java, ios, macos, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I'm using Java APNS (com.notnoop.apns, v0.2.3) to send Push Notifications to my iOS app. I'm creating the APNS service with the following lines:

```
private ApnsService createApnsService() throws IOException {
        ApnsServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = APNS.newService().withCert(certResource.getInputStream(), certPassword);
        serviceBuilder.withSandboxDestination();
        return serviceBuilder.build();
}
```

And receive the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)...    <<...the stacktrace is much longer, but I've cut it of here, since nobody would read it anyway...>>
```

---

I'm guessing that my P12 certificate is incorrect. (I've also tried PEM certificate already.) At the moment I've created the P12 certificate at this way and then applied a password:

[image: Screenshot of Keychain.app]

---

**What's the correct way to create the certificate which is compatible with Java APNS?**

Comment: I created it as per this tutorial earlier this year and it worked perfectly. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960

Comment: With Java APNS or the PHP one mentioned in the tutorial? Since in the tutorial they are using PEM-certificates, due to the documentation of Java APNS you should use P12 certificates instead.

Comment: created a pem and then converted, as per instructions here http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate

Comment: I have used Java APNS and PHP based solutions

Comment: @JohnWoods Thanks for the link. Your solution with the PKCS12 certificate works. When you create this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks alot Miho, I have created an answer, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created it as per this tutorial earlier this year and it worked perfectly.

First follow this: http://raywenderlich.com/32960

Then take the created .pem and then convert, as per instructions here http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate

Answer (score 17):

I use PKCS#12 (a .p12 file). To create it I do:

1. Export the private key from the Keychain and name it `aps_private-key.p12`.
2. Convert the key with the following command
   `openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out aps_private-key.pem -in aps_private-key.p12`, make sure to enter a PEM pass phrase of at least 4 characters.
3. Download the certificate of the app from https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action. The downloaded file should be called something like `aps_development.cer`.
4. Convert the certificate with the following command `openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out aps_development.pem`
5. Generate the credentials using `openssl pkcs12 -export -in aps_development.pem -out aps_dev_credentials.p12 -inkey aps_private-key.pem`.
6. And I'm ready to use the credentials generated in step 5 (`aps_dev_credentials.p12`).

   ```
   final InputStream certificate = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
           .getResourceAsStream("aps_dev_credentials.p12");
   final char[] passwd = {'1','2','3','4'};
   final ApnsService apnsService = com.notnoop.apns.APNS.newService()
           .withCert(certificate, new String(passwd))
           .withSandboxDestination().build();
   apnsService.testConnection();
   ```